# Time taken to create an RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am relatively new to spark and I would like to know if there is anyway to know the total time taken for RDD transformation. Currently my log shows only the memory consumed by that particular RDD and doesn't show the time taken for it's transformation.

For example, when I give the command,  val Text = sc.textFile("README.md")

I get the following in my log,

`14/09/09 12:15:38 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(32856) called with curMem=0, maxMem=311387750
14/09/09 12:15:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values to memory (estimated size 32.1 KB, free 296.9 MB)
Text: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MappedRDD[1] at textFile at :12`

Is there any way to get the time taken for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont understand the difference between a transformation and an action, then you should read some documentation before trying to write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a RDD, you're just declaring an object, the time taken will be milliseconds. Likewise for [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) like map, filter, and so on. No tasks are actually run until you perform an [action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) like count, take, collect, and so on.

When you invoke an action, the log will include timing data.

```
scala> sc.textFile("filename").count
...
14/09/09 12:38:43 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (count at <console>:13) finished in 0.984 s
14/09/09 12:38:43 INFO spark.SparkContext: Job finished: count at <console>:13, took 1.070632705 s
res1: Long = 380868
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you have a huge dataset and you are going to filter it, will it not take some time?

Comment: Yes, but filter is a transformation and is lazily evaluated. It will take time, but not at the moment you call filter.

Comment: Probably a good way to think of it is that you create a filter, not call it. You call actions (and they run jobs, processing all their parent RDDs), you create transformations.